# Add Text with CSS to Top Bar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, text, addition

I a m trying to use CSS to add some text onto the top green bar and have it centres on [this](http://camerabeanbags.co.uk/test/) website.

It is a wordpress website and i can't figure out how to add the text onto the top bar.
Any help with the CSS or HTML if required would be a big help.

Thanks

Comment: It must be in `header.php`.

Comment: You should add the text in HTML and use CSS for styling and positioning.  Word press might not allow you access to that element, however.  From inspecting the green bar it is actually two divs for left and right.  You will need to add a third div for center i'd say. CSS Flexbox is a good way for styling such components

Comment: How can i add HTML into wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with multiple ways.
You already have two divs floating right and left in the header. 
You can have 3 divs with md-4 each and use the 2nd one for your text. Also apply text-align center to that text.

One possible dirty hack could be
`<div style="position:absolute;left:50%"> <span> HEADING HERE
        </span> </div>`
Inserting something like this inside the `<div class='row'>`

Comment: How am i able to add a div to the HTML in wordpress?

Comment: Frankly speaking, I'm unaware of that. But I presume you could update the code given in the template. I just showed you how it can be done in a webpage using css and html.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bit of an odd way to do it. But if you can't edit the templates directly I guess it works

```
div#topbar:after {
  content: "Some header";
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  line-height: 34px;
}
```

Something like this would work.